Loop over column using a loop for name
I would like to  loop over a series of columns in a dataset named [GIFT_2008, GIFT_2009, ... , GIFT_2011] and replace missing values with a 0.
Ideally I would like to design a loop like this:
for i = 2008:2011
    df.GIFT_i = coalesce.(df.i, 0)
end

How can I refer to the variable i which takes the year values when specifying the column?
I have tried the above approach, as well as:
for i = 2008:2011
    df.GIFT_$i = coalesce.(df.$i, 0)
end


I assume that you have a DataFrame like this:
julia> df = DataFrame(string.("GIFT_",2008:2011) .=> eachcol(rand([missing,1:10...], 5,4)))
5×4 DataFrame
 Row │ GIFT_2008  GIFT_2009  GIFT_2010  GIFT_2011
     │ Int64?     Int64?     Int64?     Int64?
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │         5          4          9    missing
   2 │   missing          6          5          6
   3 │         9          1          7          9
   4 │         9          3          3         10
   5 │         4          8          2          5

You can use mapcols!
julia> mapcols!(x -> coalesce.(x, 0), df)
5×4 DataFrame
 Row │ GIFT_2008  GIFT_2009  GIFT_2010  GIFT_2011
     │ Int64      Int64      Int64      Int64
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │         5          4          9          0
   2 │         0          6          5          6
   3 │         9          1          7          9
   4 │         9          3          3         10
   5 │         4          8          2          5

